# To write a move assignment operator for a trivial derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, assignment-operator

I would like to know how to write a move assignment operator in the following case:

```
class Foo : public vector<int>
{
public:
  Foo(Foo&& other) : vector<int>(move(other)) {};
  Foo& operator=(Foo&& other){ ????? };
};
```

How's it done?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: There're special cases where inheriting from STL is recommended. This is not one.

Comment: The class being derived from is irrelevant, other than it should be be copyable and moveable.

Comment: You're right it's a duplicate. I suppose my question is shorter and more direct, but it's still a duplicate.

Comment: `Foo& operator = (Foo&&) & = default;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Foo
    : public vector<int>
{
public:
    auto operator=( Foo&& other )
        -> Foo&
    {
        vector<int>::operator=( move( other ) );
        return *this;
    };

    Foo( Foo&& other )
        : vector<int>( move( other ) )
    {};
};
```

Or just

```
class Foo
    : public vector<int>
{
public:
    auto operator=( Foo&& other ) -> Foo& = default;

    Foo( Foo&& other )
        : vector<int>( move( other ) )
    {};
};
```

I'm not sure of the rules for automatic generation of move assignment operator, and would currently not yet rely on the compiler implementing those rules correctly (as of June 2014).

Comment: why use the alternative function declaration syntax? does it matter?

Comment: rather, since this is the only syntax that covers all cases, it's the main syntax. the old syntax is the alternate one, only supporting a subset of functions. why use an arbitrary mix of syntaxes instead of just using the main one everywhere.